# Raspberry Pi Zero W going to sleep

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a small project using a Raspberry Pi Zero W. This is just a small Node.js server that I would like to be running at all times. I am using **Raspberry Pi OS Lite (no desktop)**

The whole thing works perfectly fine but after some time, let's say one night of no use, it stops working, until the Pi is rebooted.

I am thinking if there is any sleep mode that I am not aware of and, if that is the case, how to disable it. If not the case, I would like to hear about other possible root causes.

Comment: I would presume this will cover it [Disable raspberry pi sleep mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=260355) and [How to disable sleeping on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985964/how-to-disable-sleeping-on-raspberry-pi).

Comment: thanks! i can probably find a lot of info about how to disable it but i would like to know if this is actually the issue!!, maybe it is by far not the problem at all??

Answer (score 1):

On the RPi Zero-W, go to Raspi Configuration --> Display option. Then disable screen blanking.